# Arrays problems in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write some code that gets matrix 9X9 and two numbers: row- represents number of a row and col- represents number of a column. Zone is little matrix 3X3. the big matrix contains 9 little matrices of 3X3. the method is boolean: and it is outputs true if there are no equal numbers in the cells of little matrix 3X3 that will be located by the row and col numbers. ( the numbers can be from 1 'till 9).

I'm using a boolean array, and take advantage of its index, whenever I meet a number, I update his index-cell in the boolean array, and if I meet true twice I retuen False.
There can be a situation when the cell is empty, whenever it happens the cell contains the value "-1".
The code the compiles but does not do the work.  As you can see, I'm searching for the bounds with mod 3.

Can someone recognize a bug?

```
public static boolean isZoneValid(int row, int col, int[][] matrix) {
    int fromrow = row - (row % 3);
    int fromcol = col - (col % 3);
    boolean[] ind = new boolean[9];
    Arrays.fill(ind, false);
    for (int i = fromrow; i < fromrow + 3; i++) {
        for (int j = fromcol; j < fromcol + 3; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != -1) {
                if (ind[(matrix[i][j])-1] == true) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ind[(matrix[i][j]) - 1] = true;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "it does not work"?

Comment: sure,sometimes it returns "false" when it should returns "true".
It looks ok right?

Comment: It does look OK to me. Can you add example input that causes incorrect output?

Comment: remove `Arrays.fill(ind, false);`. `boolean` arrays are always initialized to false.

Comment: when you want to check the first row - do you pass 0 or do you pass 1 in the row parameter?

Comment: @MByd:I pass 0 for the index 0 of the first row, due to "o base".
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Add some debug output to print out the matrix before and after.  Maybe you've simply got rows and columns mixed up somewhere.  Write some test cases with JUnit

Comment: Works fine for me, but maybe I didn't meet your error case, can you post an example of array and the call to the method that fails?

Comment: @MByD: thank you for the help. Mostly when the matrix contains "-1"s,
I become to think that maybe the "check-row" or "check-col" of mine are problamatic.

Comment: @Nir. it seems like this method is fine.

Comment: BTW `row - (row % 3)` can be written as `row/3*3`

Comment: It look like you are looking for two or more values of 1-9 within a 3x3 sub-matrix.  It looks like a part of a sudoku solver?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple test and it passes all of them.  Can you provide a test it does not pass?

```
int[][] a = {{7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
if (!isZoneValid(0, 0, a)) throw new AssertionError("a");
int[][] b = {{-1, -1, 9}, {-1, 2, 3}, {9, 5, 6}};
if (isZoneValid(0, 0, b)) throw new AssertionError("b");
int[][] c = {{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}};
if (!isZoneValid(0, 0, c)) throw new AssertionError("c");
```

Comment: I guess the method is fine. there's something else wrong I guess.